# Android - How to attach a file to mail without using content providers

Tags: java, android, email, email-attachments

hi im trying to create an app that creates a word file and sends it through the mail.
so far i managed to create the file, and the necessary intent for invoking a mail app chooser,
however i encountered 2 issues:

1)i receive a list containing more than mail programs - wifi, BT etc show as well

2)if i choose gmail see the file name as an attachment in gmail however after sending it i receive no file.
i tried to swich to using URI instead of Uri but then i get javaNullExeption when gmail try to attach the file.

the question is:how to send the attachment (without use of complicated classes like content providers if possible)

the code i used:

to create the file:

```
public void saveFile(String fileName,String content) throws IOException,FileNotFoundException
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = getContext().openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        fos.write(content.getBytes());
        fos.close();    
    }
```

to send it:

```
public void sendAsMail(Context context,String fileName)
{
    File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileName);
    //file.setReadable(true);
    //URI myUri = file.toURI();
            Uri myUri=Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, context.getResources().getString(R.string.free_search_mail_subject));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,context.getResources().getString(R.string.free_search_mail_content));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send the file using:"));
}
```

i tested the file to see it is created properly (printed it using scanner) and it doesnt seem to be the problem

Comment: Try to check if file exists in sendAsMail: file.exists(). You can also try to log the Uri content using myUri.toString() to check if it's ok.

Comment: i tested it i get the file exists: I/System.out(30122): true
and the uri is: file:///data/data/com.project.mishnayot/files/print.doc but it still doesnt work for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check file is created or not. If it is created, try using this code:

```
public static void sendAsMail(File file, Context econtext) {
    try {
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/*");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "" });
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC,
                new String[] {});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "FROM Sample");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "HI");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                Uri.parse(file.toURI().toString()));
        mContext.startActivity(emailIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

If it Doesn't works then comment.

Comment: o this works, for some reason emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.toURI().toString())); works while emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri); doesnt